# What's an eloquent way to say " Please rush my request"?

Tags: formality

I would like to ask the person from whom I am requesting service, to do so quickly. I would not like to come across as rude, nor brash.

Thank you

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could expedite this request.

Comment: I like this it sounds polite whilst, expressing gratitude.

Comment: Just so you know, the most polite form you find can still be met with Get Lost, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

The more common expression is “as soon as possible”, often abbreviated as [ASAP](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/asap?s=t):

***[As soon as:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/as-soon-as)***

> At the earliest moment that, as in *Telephone me as soon as you can*. ***It often takes the form as soon as possible, meaning at the earliest possible moment***, as in *He'll finish the work as soon as possible*.

(Dictionary.com)

> Please attend to my request asap (as soon as possible)